# How to escape "!@#$()" these types of characters from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

My app use AFNetworking to call for json from web service. then I get some details from it and display using UILable. But in some places these type of characters are displaying. I want to stop this. help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried using a backslash to escape? This is usually the way to escape characters. eg. `\!\@\#\$\(\)`

Comment: If you want something more complex take a look at regular expressions - http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet